# visualforce page javascript button click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I have a visualforce page (Salesforce) where I'm trying to capture the user pressing enter in a text field and firing a button click.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#thisPage\\:theForm\\:siteNumber").keypress(function() { 
    if(window.event){                           
        key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE, chrome
    } 
    else{                           
        key = e.which;     //firefox               
    }
    if(key == 13) {
        $("#thisPage\\:theForm\\:siteButton").click();                  
    }    
});
});
```

Its very odd, I've verified the key equals 13 and its entering the if statement. I've also tried moving the .click() action above the if key==13 condition and it fires fine. It just doesn't work inside the if key==13 condition I know its entering.

I've recreated what its basically doing in this simple fiddle, but of course it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2adPe/

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:

I've figured out that this will work

```
function noenter(e){               
if(window.event){                    
    key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE, Chrome            
} 
else{                    
    key = e.which;     //firefox               
}               
if(key == 13) {                    
    document.getElementById('thisPage:theForm:siteButton').click();                                                                         
    return false;               
} 
else{                    
    return true;               
}          
}
```

with

```
onkeypress="return noenter(event)"
```

on the textbox. Is there a way to do this unobtrusively??

Answer (score 4):

Try referencing your element IDs using the [jQuery Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

Like this:

```
$("[id$='input1']").on("keypress",function(e) { // e is the current event
    if(e){ 
      key = e.keyCode; // IE, chrome
    }
    else{ 
      key = e.which; // firefox               
    }
    if(key == 13) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent a form submit when pressing enter (on IE)
      $("[id$='siteButton']").click(); // simulate a click of the siteButton
    }
});
```

Also, you'll want to prevent the default action if the `key == 13`. Otherwise, the button click might be executed twice.

http://jsfiddle.net/2adPe/3/

Comment: First, thanks for that tip on the ends with selector thats great! Second, I think you're on to something when I press enter in the text field I believe its refreshing the page because I lose my URL parameters. The e.preventdefault() isn't stopping it though.

Comment: also updated my original post with working solution I hope i can do unobtrusively

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it! I had to remove the e.preventdefault() from before the .click() and add return false at the end that stopped the default action from happening.

```
$('input[name$="siteNumber"]').keypress(function() { 
    if(window.event){                           
        key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE, chrome
    } 
    else{                           
        key = e.which;     //firefox               
    }
    if(key == 13) {
        $('input[name$="siteButton"]').click(); 
        return false;                      
    }    
});
```